# How do you use a com.amazonaws.s3-global.accesspoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, aws-private-link

I've been trying to figure out how to get a Interface based Endpoint for `com.amazonaws.s3-global.accesspoint` to work. I was able to successfully connect to my VPC dns seems to resolve to a private ip but I can't figure out how to actually use the interface access point.

For example,  I have a bucket in eu-north-1 and a VPC in ca-central-1 with the interface endpoint configured. If I download a file from S3 within the VPC is transits over the internet using the NAT Gateway, however if I'm reading the pricing document it's cheaper to use privateLink to transfer between services, and the Global S3 endpoint feels like exactly what I'm looking for.

```
admin@ip-10-101-0-126:~$ dig bucket.vpce-{ID}.accesspoint.s3-global.ca-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com

{SNIP}

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bucket.vpce-{ID}.accesspoint.s3-global.ca-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bucket.vpce-{ID}.accesspoint.s3-global.ca-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 10.101.1.98
bucket.vpce-{ID}.accesspoint.s3-global.ca-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 10.101.0.96

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.101.0.2#53(10.101.0.2)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 14 08:00:45 EST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 153
```

However when I try and use the endpoint the connection hangs.

```
admin@ip-10-101-0-126:~$ aws s3 --region ca-central-1 --endpoint-url https://bucket.vpce-{ID}.accesspoint.s3-global.ca-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com ls
```

As far as I can tell the endpoint and bucket are wide open for my account, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

I have been using [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#accessing-bucket-and-aps-from-interface-endpoints) among others to try and get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using interface VPC endpoint. It looks like you have configured Multi-Region Access Points and because of which it is not working.
Interface endpoints for Amazon S3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#accessing-bucket-and-aps-from-interface-endpoints

Multi-Region Access Points in Amazon S3:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MultiRegionAccessPoints.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I actually did switch to a VPC endpoint a while back and that solved my issue. I also ended up moving resources around and using Acceleration endpoints and it works a charm.